# LightSwitch Entity: Updating the Value of Foreign Key Property

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am struggling with how I do the following in LightSwitch.  I am 'intercepting' the entity during the `partial void tblStaffExtendeds_Updating(tblStaffExtended entity)` and then pulling some data from our local `ldap` and trying to set one of the properties of the entity to a specific value, like so:

```
partial void tblStaffExtendeds_Updating(tblStaffExtended entity)
    {

        string ldapPath = @"LDAP://DC=myLDAP,DC=myLDAP";            
        string user = entity.GPEmployeeID.ToString();
        string[] props = { 
                            ActiveDirectoryInfo.strings.DISPLAYNAME, ActiveDirectoryInfo.strings.EMAIL, 
                            ActiveDirectoryInfo.strings.LOGONALIAS, ActiveDirectoryInfo.strings.PHONE, 
                            ActiveDirectoryInfo.strings.OFFICE, ActiveDirectoryInfo.strings.TITLE, 
                            ActiveDirectoryInfo.strings.GPEMPLOYEEID
                          };

        var propResults = ActiveDirectoryInfo.UserPropertySearchByGPEmpID(user, ldapPath, props);

        entity.tblAdminStaffType.StaffType = propResults[ActiveDirectoryInfo.strings.TITLE];
        entity.WorkEmail = propResults[ActiveDirectoryInfo.strings.EMAIL];
        entity.UserID = propResults[ActiveDirectoryInfo.strings.LOGONALIAS];
        entity.WorkPhone = propResults[ActiveDirectoryInfo.strings.PHONE];
   }
```

Now for fields like `WorkEmail` and `WorkPhone` this works fine as those properties are just `strings` and that is what I am getting from `LDAP`.
However I do I go about setting the `StaffType` which is a reference to an Admin Table entry?  LDAP returns a `string` which matches the description on the Admin Table but on the Entity I would need to set it to the correct ID, I am assuming.

Is there someway to do this, short of creating "Look Up" methods to find the ID from the Admin Table by matching the Description to my `String` from `LDAP`?

Answer (score 1):

The solution should look something like this:

```
string title = propResults[ActiveDirectoryInfo.strings.TITLE];

var qryAdminStaffType = from st in DataWorkspace.ApplicationData.StaffTypes
                        where st.Title == title
                        select st;

entity.tblAdminStaffType.StaffType = qryAdminStaffType.FirstOrDefault();
```

In this example, I'm assuming that your data source is called ApplicationData (the LS default name), that the *StaffTypes* table holds your staff types, and that you are matching the *Title* attribute. Note that if there is no match to the title, FirstOrDefalt() will return null.